# SAML2.0 for Spring 4 based application

Tags: spring, spring-security, saml-2.0, shiro, picketlink

I'm new bee to SAML. I just want to know which all Security integration framework will go good with below set of framework and server.

1. Spring 4
2. Jboss EAP6
3. Hibernate application
4. SAML 2.0
5. Single sign-on
6. Page wise authorization
7. Only internal users with proper Auth Function & Data elements.

I have seen Spring SAML, Picketlink, Apache Shiro, Keycloak, Shibboleth. In these five framework, which will go good for my above framework, server and requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Spring + Jboss will go good with Picketlink and Spring security for SAML implementation.